# Hiding command prompt while starting a process in C++

Tags: c++, winapi

I have to start a process from my C++ code. I am using CreateProcess() function and I have set the following flags in the startupinfo struct. But still the command prompt shows up which I have to close manually to proceed. Please tell me how I can hide this command prompt during th e start up of the process.

```
si.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);
    si.dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
    si.wShowWindow = SW_HIDE;
```

the create process call looks like this:

```
CreateProcess( NULL,   // No module name (use command line)
        exe,            // Command line
        NULL,           // Process handle not inheritable
        NULL,           // Thread handle not inheritable
        FALSE,          // Set handle inheritance to FALSE
        CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE,              // No creation flags
        NULL,           // Use parent's environment block
        NULL,           // Use parent's starting directory 
        &si,            // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
        &pi );
```

exe is a string containing the process name to start.

Please tell me how to hide this command prompt during start up of the process.
I tried the method described [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2537/Running-console-applications-silently) but it doesn't work. I have a Windows 7 system.

Thanks,
Rakesh.

Comment: Are you the author of the other program? If so, is the entry point `main()` or `WinMain()` ?

Comment: No, I am not the author of the other program, so I don't know which one of them is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As MSalters says, the `CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE` is not what you want. But you probably also want to pass `CREATE_NO_WINDOW` to the `CreateProcess` function. See the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684863%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on what you can pass to `CreateProcess` as flags.

Comment: I changed to CREATE_NO_WINDOW but still it doesn't solve my problem. Am I missing anything?

Comment: CREATE_NO_WINDOW is enough. Sounds like the other program is creating the console with AllocConsole.

Answer (score 1):

You're passing `CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE` and you do NOT want a new console window. Seems like the answer is entirely obvious. Still, if the other process creates a console itself, then you cant prevent it. What happens if you start that process via Explorer?

Comment: The other process does not start any command prompt when started from explorer.